# NumberFormatException on DecimalFormat Float

Tags: android, floating-point, numberformatexception, textwatcher

after many attempts I managed to create a pattern for Float , I managed to do it by return ActivityResult and set it in the corresponding field . Now I have a problem with this TextWatcher that does not accept the pattern of Float , can anyone help me out ?

This is the TextWather

```
   private abstract class TextChangedListener implements TextWatcher
{

    public abstract void numberEntered(Float number);

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        String text = s.toString();
        try
        {
            Float parsedFloat = Float.valueOf(text);
            numberEntered(parsedFloat);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            Log.w(getPackageName(), "Non si puo' parsare '" + text + "' col numero", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
    }
}
```

This is the Float pattern

```
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ITALIAN));
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue?

Comment: It's going in NumberFormatException. If I write 90 `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "90,00"`

Comment: `float` is an integer value, but has large range than `int`. So that, you got `NumberFormatException` because the number format is in decimal, not in integer.

Comment: `numberEntered` is used by the TextWather to read the two Float which are used in a subtraction

Comment: float: "90,00", here 90 and 00  are two numbers?

Comment: No it's a formatted float 90,00 from number 90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all! I resolve my problem with this method!

```
    private void decimalFormatWithSymbol() {
    dec = new DecimalFormat("##0.00", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ITALIAN));
    dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    dec.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give some decimal numbers to `float`, convert it to `double`:

```
float f = 90;
DecimalFormat decimal2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); // gives 2 numbers after '.'
double dec = Double.valueOf(decimal2.format(f));
```

Above code will gives you the output:

```
90.00
```

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly due to the Locale issue, just define **locale as English** your issue will be resolved.

```
 public double convertTwoDecimalPointAmount(double amount) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
        return Double.parseDouble(df.format(amount));
    }
```